# How do I know the VM RAM size for a particular build in Travis CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

Travis CI allows us to adjust [RAM size](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/#vm-instance-size). For a past build, how do I know the RAM size of the VM instance? My main use case is to understand whether my VM size configuration has taken effects.

Answer (score 0):

The default VM resources are listed here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/#virtualisation-environment-vs-operating-system

Using

```
vm: 
 size: []
```

the option will double the size of your resources(CPU + RAM) to double in each level.